# C: How to know if current input has \b in it

Tags: c, input

Good day, how do you know if there is a backspace (\b) in an input string? cuz from what i know, i just move the cursor back, rubs out the nearest character where \b is written. How will i know that there is a \b in there? Tnx

Answer (score 2):

You can look for any character in a string with `strchr`.  That said, you will not normally see backspaces in your input because your terminal (tty) will be in *cooked* mode (instead of *raw* mode) which means that the kernel will be handling things like backspace within a line until you hit return and then the entire (edited) string will be passed to your program.

Programs like your shell put the tty in raw mode so they can do more extensive editing (usually full Emacs or vi-like editing).  When you launch a program (such as your own) from a shell it puts it back into cooked mode first.

Comment: ohhh so thats how it works, how about getchar().. checking every input like so while(c = getchar() != EOF) and so on, i have an if statment like this if(c == '\b') but the problem is it wont detect.. so that being said, it is also cooked? if so, is there any way to detect this?

Comment: You can use curses and this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772341/how-to-get-a-character-from-stdin-without-waiting-for-user-to-put-it  Or here's a more low level answer;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548434/get-an-input-from-keyboard-without-return-in-c

Comment: One of those answers mentions *cbreak* mode, which is halfway between cooked and raw.  See:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface

Comment: I would avoid the use of the ancient and often confusing terms "cooked" and "raw" (and "line mode" and "cbreak") and instead use the same term POSIX now uses uniformly:  "canonical mode".  The terminal interface is either in _canonical mode_ or it's not, and if it's not then certain parameters control when characters are made available, and how many are made available at a time.